# How to create Git repository accessible via ssh on Windows?

Tags: windows, git, ssh, cygwin, openssh

I am using Git 1.9.4 and latest Cygwin on Window 7 (x86).

Now I am trying to create a remote repository that i can access over SSH.

I created a bare repository
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKl2G.png

than i tried to do a push but without success
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKg28.png

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Installed and configured cygwin and OpenSSH using this article http://therightstuff.de/CommentView,guid,b969ea4d-8d2c-42af-9806-de3631f4df68.aspx

Comment: Can you just plain ssh into the system?

Comment: sorry , don't understand your question

Comment: What happens if you type `ssh youruser@whateverhost`?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MJhWX.png

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you need to add the final '/'? Even though you are specifying a directory, I've always had success using the repo name without the final '/' (`.../Project.git` rather than `.../Project.git/`).

Comment: If you know say please under windows from what place exactly I need to start the patch, from Home( c:/users/toco2 ) - /repositories/Project  , full patch /c/users/toco2/repositories/Project or other variant ?